# Sphinx Index/Replace Curly Apostrophes

Tags: sphinx

I asked this previously as a Regex question yet the issue appears to be Sphinx as even the correct Regex set-up failed in Sphinx. So: Is there a way to convert curly apostrophes in the index to straight ones? I have tried:

- **Exceptions.text**: ’ => '
- **regexp using the actual character**: regexp_filter=(\w+)\’s=>\1
- **regexp using the unicode**: regexp_filter=(\w+)\x{2019}s=>\1

And nothing has worked. I get that the `’` may fail because these are text files but not sure why unicode would. In any event the `’` is breaking things for me and I'd hate to do mysql replace on the entire database just for this.

Comment: Have you considered http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ignore-chars

Comment: @barryhunter I tried `ignore_chars = U+2019` and no luck. I'm still forced to manually remove. So far sphinx does not recognize that either as an explicit character `’` or as unicode `U+2019`. In an ideal world I'd be able to remap U+2019 to the standard `'` but at this point would just love to remove it in the index as my last option is to do a massive mysql replace for each `’`

Comment: If the regex is not working right, maybe ther data reaching indexer (when rexexp_filter is actully applied, si not actully proper UTF8 encoded? are you using SET NAMES in a sql_query_pre for example?